# XPath - Select LAST occurence of String

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I've got this tree:

```
<Events>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314022</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314023</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314024</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314022</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314023</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314024</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>

</Events>
```

How can I select `<Descriptor=200>` values with no duplicates? For example in this case I only need to select `ABC1234` and `123456` once.

UPDATE: I need to iterate at `Events` level and then select the distinct Strings.

Comment: You want to achieve this result in SQL Server or something else ???

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the last, or no duplicated values?

For no duplicated values:

```
distinct-values(//Property[@Descriptor=200])
```

For the last

```
(//Property[@Descriptor=200])[last()]
```

(assuming Descriptor is a property, and you lost the `<Property` beginning when posting the xml, since the file you posted is not a valid xml)

Comment: XML fixed. Sorry for the mistake. It didn't work as I am trying to iterate at Events level so I assume I need to find the number of different strings before selecting them. I'll add this to the question description. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath, it selects distinct values:

```
//Property[@Descriptor = 200]
    [not(. = ../following-sibling::Properties/Property[@Descriptor = 200])]
```